# Error involving incremental (C1073) compilation when compiling an external library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2012

I need to compile an external library using DirectX, from a VS2008 project.
I've converted it to a VS2012 project, but the project doesn't compile.

I get the following error in many files:

```
> fatal error C1073: Internal error involving incremental compilation 
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\p0io.c', line 865)
```

What is the meaning of this error?

And what is the `p0io.c` file? I've no file with this name (nor a `f://` disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the output generated by the `__FILE__` macro inside the MSVC compiler.  The F: drive was the drive used on the build machine in Redmond to store the source code.  `dd` means DevDiv, the subdivision of the Servers and Tools division of Microsoft that is responsible for the developer tool products, like MSVC.  The `p0` in the file name gives a hint where the compiler crashed, p0 is the preprocessor pass.  So some sort of problem with macros is likely.  Albeit that `io` hints at trouble with a file.

No code to look at so I can only recommend the documented workaround for C1073.  Disable incremental compilation with Project + Properties, C/C++, General, Debug Information Format setting.  Change it from the default of /ZI to /Zi and rebuild your project.  Delete any .pch file in the build directory by hand first, to be sure.  Hopefully you'll now get error messages that provides a hint why your code made the compiler take a nosedive.  Fix those and with some luck you can turn /ZI back on.

If you still have trouble and you repro this issue with VS2012 then you can file a bug report at connect.microsoft.com.  They'll need a copy of your project to repro the issue.  If you can't wait or use an old version then call Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 23):

For VS2010, Disabling Configuration properties | C/C++ | Code generation | "minimal rebuild"   avoids the error.

Comment: This tip helped, as opposed to the accepted answer about the disabling incremental compilation.

Comment: It helped me too. Im using a project that is located in a network device. I know sometimes dates are not recognized exactly. maybe that's why it fails. I tried to disable the incremental build but the problem persisted until i disabled minimal rebuild. 
(I'm compiling my soft in a virtual machine because i'm actually runnign gnu-linux)

Comment: Indeed it did. Thanks!

Comment: Still solves the problem in VS2019.